# How to start a new line with Emacs

Tags: unix, emacs

I have created a file using emacs but when I open the file all the text comes in one line. What do I enter in emacs so that when I open the file there will be more than one line?

Comment: When you open the file in what?

Comment: I open the file with notepad

Comment: Why is this tagged 'unix' if you are using notepad (by which I presume you are referring to the default text editor under Windows) ?

Comment: @phils, good question. I suspect that the OP is creating the file on one machine and opening it on another, and believed the problem to be on the Unix / Emacs end instead of the Windows / Notepad end. But only gexcen can answer for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad is a very limited text editor that doesn't support, among other things, Unix-style [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`<LF>`). To save a file in Emacs that will open up properly in Notepad, you need to save it with Windows-style line endings (`<CR><LF>`).

Likely the easiest solution is to run `set-buffer-file-coding-system` (bound to `C-x RET f` by default) and choose `undecided-dos`, then save the buffer.

Note that this is a limitation of Notepad; files created with Unix-style line endings under Emacs can generally be opened without issue on any number of other text editors, including Vim, Sublime Text, Notepad++, and most IDEs. Simply installing a decent text editor on your Windows machine may be a good alternative to saving with Windows line endings.

Answer (score 1):

If Notepad shows the data in one line then that probably means that emacs is not using `CRLF` as the line terminator.

You can tell emacs to set the line-terminator to `CRLF` by entering the command <kbd>Control-X</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> then when prompted for a coding system, type `dos` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This should be the default if you're using NT-emacs (the windows version of Emacs).